# Eclipse (Mars 4.5.1) installed with the Eclipse Installer does not recognize new plugin

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-mars, oomph

after copying a plugin to the plugin-folder (C:\Users\myUserName.p2\pool\plugins)
eclipse does not show/use this plugin.

This is the first time i used the installer for eclipse and i did not expect that you can't copy plugins anymore.

Does that mean i have to go back to the zip package?

-Christian

Comment: Just copying things to the plugins folder has not been guaranteed to work for a long time. Try starting with the -clean option.

Comment: thanks but I tried that too. what would be the right way to add our custom  birt extension plugin to eclipse these days

Comment: Creating a feature and using 'Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable features' gives you something that can be installing using 'Install new software'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not directly linked to the new Eclipse Installer.

[image: Eclipse P2 Update Site]

A P2 Update site (this is also more or less what you bundle pool is) consists of folders (`plugins`, `features` …) containing jars and/or bin files and some XML Files named `artifacts.xml` and `content.xml` (sometimes those files are also packed in `jar` files).

The XML Files keep a record of the available plugins. You cannot add something manually without tampering your pool.

You should install additional plugins with the “Install new software…” of Eclipse. If you like to automate this installation process for each of your installations (or inside a team), you can work with the Oomph setup file to do it.